# Cannot get component to update after state is updated

Tags: reactjs

I'm rendering a table using ReactTable.

```
export class ItemHandler extends React.Component<IitemsProps, IitemState> {
    constructor(props: IitemsProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: [], 
            columns: [
                { Header: 'Name', accessor: 'Name', sortable: true },
                { Header: 'ID', accessor: 'ID', sortable: true }
            ],
            selectedRow: {} as Iitem,
            isLoaded: false,
            Item: {} as Iitem
          }

          this._saveNewItem = this._saveNewItem.bind(this);
          this.onFieldChange = this.onFieldChange.bind(this);
    }
    public componentDidMount(): void {
        // Code for fetching data...
    }
    render() {
        const {items, columns, selectedRow } = this.state;

        return(
            <div>
                <CommandButton
                    data-automation-id="addItem"
                    iconProps={{ iconName: 'AddTo' }}
                    text="Add new item"
                    onClick={this.createNewItemDialog}
                />

                <ReactTable 
                    data={items}
                    columns={columns}
                    defaultPageSize={items.length}
                    resizable={false}
                    loading={false}
                    showPagination={false}
                    showPaginationTop={false}
                    showPaginationBottom={false}
                    showPageSizeOptions={false}
                />

                <Dialog
                    hidden={this.state.hideCreateNewItemDialog}
                    >
                    <CreateNewDialogContent 
                        selectedRow={selectedRow}
                        saveNewItem={this._saveNewItem} 
                        />
                </Dialog>
            </div>
        )
    }

    private _saveNewItem = (selectedRow:Iitem) => {

        //selectedRow comes from CreateNewDialogComponent
        const updatedItem = selectedRow;
        updatedItem.Name = selectedRow.Name;
        updatedItem.ID = selectedRow.ID;

           fetch(`${remoteWebLocation.origin}/api/tblName${remoteWebLocation.search}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: 'include',
                headers: new Headers({
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Accept: "application/json"
                }),
                body: JSON.stringify(this.state.Item)
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {

                    const newData = this.state.items;

                    newData.push({
                        Name: updatedItem.Name,
                        ID: updatedItem.ID
                    })

                    this.setState({
                        items:newData
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And in my Child Component:

```
export class CreateNewDialogContent extends React.Component<IDialogProps, IDialogState> {
constructor(props: IDialogProps) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
}
render() {
    let selectedRow = this.props.selectedRow;

    return (
    <div>
        <DialogContent>
            <TextField 
                required
                label="Name" 
                value={selectedRow.Name}
            />
            <TextField 
                required
                label="ID" 
                value={selectedRow.ID} 
            />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogFooter>
            <PrimaryButton 
                onClick={() => this.saveNewItem(selectedRow)} 
                disabled={_disabled} 
                text="Save" 
            />
        </DialogFooter>
    </div>
    )
}

private saveNewItem = (selectedRow:IItem) => {

    //This sends selectedRow to parent function saveNewItem.
    this.props.saveNewItem(selectedRow);

}
}
```

When I'm debugging in the _saveNewLanguage (in parent Component) I can see the correct values, and when it do the POST I can see the state updates (with the push) and adds the new value, but the table does not update.

I've tried many different solutions found here on stackoverflow, but no success. Can anyone see why it won't update?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I tried creating a simple Component that renders items instead of ReactTable, and it works fine. So it seems to be a problem with ReactTable.

Comment: My guess is because it's doing a shallow compare with the new state and those are equal.  Have you tried using the ```shouldComponentUpdate``` lifecycle method comparing something nested a little deeper?

Comment: I've tried that. But when I click the <CommandButton /> the shouldComponentUpdate fires and the state hasn't changed, so it returns false and the dialog never opens. Not sure how I can compare "something nested a Little deeper", in the Child Component you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mutating the state, which is bad. Even though the new item has been added to the array, it's still the same *array instance*. When this gets passed down to your table, `oldTable === newTable` will be true. Your state should be immutable, meaning you should always return a new object or array instead of mutating them in place. For arrays you can spread them into a new array and add the new item at the end. Like this in your `_saveNewItem` method:

```js
// after the fetch()
.then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        this.setState(state => ({
            items: [
                ...state.items,
                {
                    Name: updatedItem.Name,
                    ID: updatedItem.ID
                }
            ]
        }));
    }
});
```

Comment: I can see the new item in the this.state.items (when I check the state in dev tools), but it's not refreshing the ReactTable with the new state.

Comment: I updated my answer to be a bit more descriptive. If you use the code there now, does it still fail to update?

Comment: It works when I just do a simple Component that list items with divs. But when I do this with ReactTable (data=items) it doesn't work.

Comment: I made some mistakes along the way, but your solution finally works now. Thanks.